# Is there a way to find all the unique URLs crawled by Google in a specific domain?

Tags: url, google-search, googlebot, google-crawlers

I was wondering if there was a way to get all the URLs (including sub-domains) that Google search crawler has crawled?

Answer (score 0):

You can only find the pages Google have *indexed* (not just crawled) by searching this:

```
site:example.com
```